# IllegalStateException: Already connected with HttpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode

Tags: java, http

I know this question has been asked a few times here but I've tried everything. It may be completely my fault as this is my first time doing this but if it is then at least I'll be able to improve.

Relevant code:

```
URL url = new URL(request);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",
                "Bot (token)");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/reference, 1.0.0");
        connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(connection.getContentLength());

        switch (connection.getResponseCode()) {
        case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK:
            break;
        case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED:
            Executor.logger.warning("Connection to Discord API does not have sufficient authorization!");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED
                    + "An unrelated error occured in the server, please report this to a staff member.");
            return;
        default:
            Executor.logger.warning(
                    "An unknown exception occured with the HTTP Error Code: " + connection.getResponseCode());
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Linking your accounts has failed!");
            TextComponent message = new TextComponent(ChatColor.AQUA + ChatColor.BOLD.toString() + "click here!");
            message.setClickEvent(new ClickEvent(ClickEvent.Action.OPEN_URL, "https://www.mcpz.net"));
            player.sendMessage(
                    ChatColor.YELLOW + "For information on how to find your ID, " + message.toPlainText());
            return;

        }
```

Console error:

```
    org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'link' in plugin DiscordBridge v1.0.0
    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46) ~[squid-spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4af49dc-c5e9a16]
    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) ~[squid-spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4af49dc-c5e9a16]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_9_R2.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:645) ~[squid-spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4af49dc-c5e9a16]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R2.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1349) [squid-spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4af49dc-c5e9a16]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R2.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1184) [squid-spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4af49dc-c5e9a16]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R2.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:45) [squid-spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4af49dc-c5e9a16]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R2.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:1) [squid-spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4af49dc-c5e9a16]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R2.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [squid-spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4af49dc-c5e9a16]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R2.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:45) [squid-spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4af49dc-c5e9a16]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R2.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:726) [squid-spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4af49dc-c5e9a16]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R2.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:399) [squid-spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4af49dc-c5e9a16]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R2.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:665) [squid-spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4af49dc-c5e9a16]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R2.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:564) [squid-spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4af49dc-c5e9a16]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at uk.co.harieo.DBridge.Discord.Broadcaster.responseMinorUpdate(Broadcaster.java:161) ~[?:?]
    at uk.co.harieo.DBridge.LinkingCommand.onCommand(LinkingCommand.java:39) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[squid-spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4af49dc-c5e9a16]
    ... 15 more
```

I have tried moving the methods around, using connection.disconnet() but it always returns this exception. As I've found out, the HttpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode() is required for connected to the API I am trying to use or else it returns HTTP Error 411.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Thanks for any help in advance
- Harieo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(connection.getContentLength());
```

The problem is here. By calling `getContentLength()` you are committing the request and attempting to read the response, and then you're trying to set the length of the request. It doesn't make sense. The parameter you need to supply is how much data you're going to send, not how much the server is going to send back.

You also need to *write* something, again *before* you get the response code or do anything else that implies fetching the response.

> As I've found out, the HttpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode() is required for connected to the API I am trying to use or else it returns HTTP Error 411.

I don't see how you can tell with this code. All you've done by adding `setFixedLengthStreamingMode()` is change the error. More likely the problem was that you didn't send anything.

NB You need to set the request method to PUT *after* calling `setDoOutput(true)`, because that sets it to POST.

Comment: How exactly do you get the content length without calling for the server response?

Comment: You don't need the content length when setting fixed length streaming mode. I've explained all this already. The parameter is the length of the request, not of the response.

Comment: Maybe I am using the term 'content' wrong, I'm asking how to find the parameter required for the method not anything to do with the server response.

Comment: Once again, I have already told you: 'the paraneter you need to supply is how much data you're going to send'..

Comment: Once again, I ask if there is a method to finding out how much data I'm sending without encountering my original problem.

Comment: How would I know? It's your data. Is it a string?  A file? You're not sending anything at the moment, so you already have a prior bug. I am trying to get you to understand that the length of what you're going to send doesn't have anything to do with the length of the response. It can't, because the request has to be sent before the response can be returned.

Comment: I don't understand what I am supposed to be sending here, I thought the connection.setRequestProperty("User Agent", "https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/reference, 1.0.0") was what I am sending. Have I missed out a vital part of using this or something?

Comment: No. That's only a header. You are doing a PUT. That means you're going to get the output stream of the `URLConnection` and write something to it. If you must set fixed length transfer mode, which I doubt, it is the length of that written data that you must supply, exactly. Or else you have completely misunderstood your specification.

Comment: I'm following a specific HTTP API that doesn't require any content with the PUT type, as the link itself contains all the information. The link is formatted as (example) www.api.com/server/ID/user/ID/whattogive/itemID. Is that not compatible with HttpURLConnection in Java? (Also the header with the authentication)

Comment: So the value you need is zero. Why you would need fixed length streaming mode for that remains a mystery. You could try just getting and closing the output stream, just to satisfy my curiousity.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know either but the code won't work without it. This works so I will set your answer to my question. Thank you for your patience, I know my knowledge is very basic.

Answer (score 1):

Under your question, just replace `connection.getContentLength()` with `requestData.length`.

TL;DR.

When you enter `setFixedLengthStreamingMode`, you will find out that the `connected` attribute has been set to `true`. Well, when is it set to `true`?

In fact, `already connected` means you have re-new the HttpURLConnection, which is the root cause.

You should check if you have written some code like this:

```
connection.getContentType, connection.getContentEncoding
```

If you do so, please comment them. The implementation of this methods use delegate pattern, which means they will new another HttpURLConnection.